# iOS application crash when started

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, crash

I have such problem
I am making an application with xcode 4.3.1 iOS 4.0 as target.

I have default picture as starting image.
I am using core data.

When I start application then type some info into it and then push it to background. Its all ok. If I try to start after I went to background it become crash after start image is loaded. Second launch is good without crashes. When I try to start application with some delay it does not crash.

The problem that I have no errors in debbuger and no logs about crash in iPod. All seems well.

If you had such problems, please say how you fix this issue.

P.S. Sorry for my English

Comment: There is not enough information here to help you. Have you tried debugging the application? Do you know *where* it crashes? If not, that would be your first goal, finding out where it crashes.

Comment: Run it in Xcode and see where it crashes

Comment: I ran in Xcode. It is not crashing in the application. It crashes only  when I try to start it again immidiately after closing. If I wait some time after closing application did not crash

Comment: Check what happen when your application goes to background and then back becomes active

Answer (score 0):

You can try using logs and check out Xcode's organizer's console for your device so you can get additional info about functions that were called last.